# Making a file upload required on a Mechanical Turk HIT

Tags: mechanicalturk

Anyone know how to specify that a file upload is required with a QuestionForm > AnswerSpecification > FileUploadAnswer? I've got this here:

```
<AnswerSpecification>
    <FileUploadAnswer>
        <MaxFileSizeInBytes>3000000</MaxFileSizeInBytes>
        <MinFileSizeInBytes>1000</MinFileSizeInBytes>
    </FileUploadAnswer>
</AnswerSpecification>
```

With a FreeTextAnswer and constraints and no entered value, the form prevents submission. But with the FileUploadAnswer, an empty value allows form submission.

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: I believe you can just add a `<IsRequired>true</IsRequired>` element to the question specification.